# How to order multiple columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

How I can order multiple columns in MySql.

I have order table.

```
Id     NewDueDate     OrigionalDate
1      13/04/19       12/04/19
2         null        10/04/19
3      09/04/19       02/04/19
```

So I want to sort of NewDueDate and OrigionalDate ASC.

Comment: Please who the results you want.

Comment: Use a comma: `ORDER BY NewDueDate, OrigionalDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY col1 ASC, col2 ASC;`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want:

```
order by coalesce(NewDueDate, OrigionalDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want ;

```
order by (case when NewDueDate is null then OrigionalDate else NewDueDate end), OrigionalDate;
```